# What is a proper paradigm for having a mutable global value in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, global-variables

So, let's say that I am displaying an integer `myInt` value in `OneViewController`. Then, while a different view is showing, `AnotherViewController`, I need to increment or decrement `myInt`.

So the scope needs to be global or at least be able to be accessed by other viewControllers and it needs to be mutable.

I know that properties one way to do this but I haven't been able to get them to work. I have been importing the header file of `OneViewController` into `AnotherViewController` but that wasn't what I was missing.

I've gone through several introductory books but multi-view controller variable work wasn't explicitly covered in any of them. Clearly I'm a beginner so please excuse any conceptual misunderstandings.

Comment: Uh, I would guess that you want a value that's global and mutable.  What specifically is the issue?

Comment: @Hotlicks Well, the super simple game I'm making depends on an integer value for it's state. When I make a property in the MainViewController for the NSInteger `state`, I am unable to access the property from another view controller. So, I'm looking for the proper way to accomplish accessing that state variable and later changing it as well.

Comment: So, you make it global somehow.  You can make it a property in your app delegate, you can use a `static` field in one of your classes and have it provide a public set of setters/getters, or you can go a little further and hack up a sorta-singleton.  I would probably just make it a property in the app delegate, but with your own setters/getters (and maybe incrementers/decrementers) so you add breakpoints and NSLogs if necessary and so you can add synchronization if that seems necessary.

Comment: Or, rather than a true global, learn how to pass parameters properly between VCs, and just make it a property of one VC.  (Just importing the header file won't hack it -- you have to pass the address of the VC that "owns" the property to the VCs that will access it.  This can be done when you create the new VCs from the "owning" one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't have to be view controllers -- any sort of custom classes.

In FirstClass.h:

```
@property(whatever) int someIntInFirstClass;
-(void) someMethodInFirstClass;
```

SecondClass.h

```
 @property(whatever) FirstClass* myParent;
```

FirstClass.m

```
SecondClass* second = [[SecondClass alloc] init];
second.myParent = self;
[second startSomething];
```

SecondClass.m:

```
[self.myParent someMethodInFirstClass];
int x = self.myParent.someIntInFirstClass;
self.myParent.someIntInFirstClass = x + 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at ReactiveCocoa library and check how the signal pattern works. The library has to offer a lot of things including the scenario you have just mentioned.

https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa

A bit of a learning curve. But worth!